# Why the controller does not get loaded sometimes?

Tags: sapui5

I have a problem, that sometimes the controller does not get loaded:

[image]

and you can see the error message. It should load the following controller(marked with red border):

[image]

Why it is not getting loaded sometimes?

When the controller gets loaded, it looks like:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I am using [flexible column layout](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/flexible-column-layout/).

The App.view.xml looks like:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="ch.mindustrie.ZMM_CLASSIFICATION.controller.App" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:f="sap.f">
    <App id="root">
        <f:FlexibleColumnLayout id="idClassLayout"/>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

the `manifest.json` file:

```
{
    "_version": "1.9.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "ch.mindustrie.ZMM_CLASSIFICATION",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "0.1.0"
        },
        "title": "{{appTitle}}",
        "description": "{{appDescription}}",
        "sourceTemplate": {
            "id": "servicecatalog.connectivityComponentForManifest",
            "version": "0.0.0"
        },
        "dataSources": {
            "ZMM_CLASSIFICATION_SRV": {
                "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMM_CLASSIFICATION_SRV/",
                "type": "OData",
                "settings": {
                    "odataVersion": "2.0",
                    "localUri": "localService/ZMM_CLASSIFICATION_SRV/metadata.xml"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sap.ui": {
        "technology": "UI5",
        "icons": {
            "icon": "",
            "favIcon": "",
            "phone": "",
            "phone@2": "",
            "tablet": "",
            "tablet@2": ""
        },
        "deviceTypes": {
            "desktop": true,
            "tablet": true,
            "phone": true
        },
        "supportedThemes": [
            "sap_hcb",
            "sap_belize"
        ]
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "handleValidation": true,
        "rootView": {
            "viewName": "ch.mindustrie.ZMM_CLASSIFICATION.view.App",
            "type": "XML",
            "async": true,
            "id": "app"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.50.0",
            "libs": {
                "sap.ui.layout": {},
                "sap.ui.core": {},
                "sap.m": {},
                "sap.f": {},
                "sap.collaboration": {
                    "lazy": true
                }
            }
        },
        "contentDensities": {
            "compact": true,
            "cozy": true
        },
        "models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "ch.mindustrie.ZMM_CLASSIFICATION.i18n.i18n"
                }
            },
            "Classification": {
                "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMM_CLASSIFICATION_SRV/",
                "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
                "settings": {
                    "defaultOperationMode": "Server",
                    "defaultBindingMode": "OneWay",
                    "defaultCountMode": "Request"
                },
                "dataSource": "ZMM_CLASSIFICATION_SRV",
                "preload": true
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "css": [
                {
                    "uri": "css/style.css"
                }
            ]
        },
        "routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.f.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "viewPath": "ch.mindustrie.ZMM_CLASSIFICATION.view",
                "controlId": "idClassLayout",
                "bypassed": {
                    "target": [
                        "search",
                        "characteristic"
                    ]
                },
                "async": true
            },
            "routes": [
                {
                    "pattern": "",
                    "name": "search",
                    "target": [
                        "characteristic",
                        "search"

                    ],
                    "layout": "TwoColumnsBeginExpanded"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "search/{internalclassnum}",
                    "name": "characteristic",
                    "target": [
                        "search",
                        "characteristic"
                    ],
                    "layout": "TwoColumnsMidExpanded"
                }
            ],
            "targets": {
                "search": {
                    "viewName": "Search",
                    "viewLevel": 1,
                    "viewId": "search",
                    "controlAggregation": "beginColumnPages"
                },
                "characteristic": {
                    "viewName": "Characteristic",
                    "viewLevel": 2,
                    "viewId": "characteristic",
                    "controlAggregation": "endColumnPages"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sap.platform.abap": {
        "uri": "/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zmm_classifi/webapp",
        "_version": "1.1.0"
    }
}
```

the `Search.view.xml`:

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:uxap="sap.uxap"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:smartFilterBar="sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar"
    controllerName="ch.mindustrie.ZMM_CLASSIFICATION.controller.Search" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar id="SelectionFilterBar" entitySet="ZMM_C_CLASSIFICATION" search="onSearchClass">
        <smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
            <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="ClassType" visibleInAdvancedArea="true" preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
            <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="ClassNum" visibleInAdvancedArea="true" preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
        </smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
    </smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar>
    <Tree id="ClassTree" items="{path: 'Tree>/'}" toggleOpenState="onOpenAnItemOnTree">
        <CustomTreeItem>
            <FlexBox width="100%" alignItems="Center" justifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                <items>
                    <Label text="{Tree>text}" wrapping="true"/>
                    <Button icon="sap-icon://display" type="Transparent" press="onClassPressed"/>
                </items>
            </FlexBox>
        </CustomTreeItem>
    </Tree>
</mvc:View>
```

And the `Search.Controller`

```
sap.ui.define([
    "ch/mindustrie/ZMM_CLASSIFICATION/controller/BaseController"
], function (BaseController) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseController.extend("ch.mindustrie.ZMM_CLASSIFICATION.controller.Search", {

        /**
         * Called when a controller is instantiated and its View controls (if available) are already created.
         * @memberOf ch.mindustrie.ZMM_CLASSIFICATION.view.Search
         */
        onInit: function () {
            //Set model for smart filter bar
            const oModel = this.getModel("Classification");
            this.setModel(oModel);

            //Model for classification tree
            this.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(), "Tree");
        },

        onSearchClass: function () {
            const aFilter = this.byId("SelectionFilterBar").getFilters();

            const self = this;
            //Build the first node
            this._readClassification(aFilter)
                .then(aData => self.getModel("Tree").setProperty("/", aData));
        },

        /*
         * Read classification from server.
         */
        _readClassification: function (aFilter) {

            const self = this;
            //Build entry node
            const oModel = this.getModel("Classification");

            const oDateFrom = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                path: "ValidFrom",
                operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.LE,
                value1: new Date()
            });

            const oDateUntil = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                path: "ValidFrom",
                operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.GE,
                value1: new Date()
            });

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                oModel
                    .read("/ZMM_C_CLASSIFICATION", {
                        filters: aFilter.concat([oDateFrom, oDateUntil]),
                        success: function (oData) {
                            let aTreeWithNodes = [];
                            const aTree = oData.results.map(self._buildEntryTree);

                            aTree.forEach((oNode, index) => {

                                self._readSubClasses(oNode.internalClass)
                                    .then(aData => {
                                        const oWithNodes = aTree[index];
                                        if (aData.length > 0) {
                                            oWithNodes.nodes = aData;
                                        }
                                        aTreeWithNodes.push(oWithNodes);
                                        if (aTreeWithNodes.length === aTree.length) {
                                            resolve(aTreeWithNodes);
                                        }
                                    });
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (oError) {
                            reject(oError);
                        }
                    });
            });
        },

        _readSubClasses: function (sSubInternalClass) {
            const oModel = this.getModel("Classification");
            const self = this;

            const oUpInteralClass = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                path: "UpInternalClass",
                operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,
                value1: sSubInternalClass
            });

            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                oModel
                    .read("/ZMM_C_CLASSSUB_REL", {
                        filters: [oUpInteralClass],
                        success: function (oData) {
                            const aNewNodes = (oData.results.length > 0 ? oData.results.map(self._prepareDescEntryNodes) : []);
                            resolve(aNewNodes);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            resolve([]);
                        }
                    });
            });

        },

        /*
         * Build the entry node.
         */
        _buildEntryTree: function (oData) {
            return {
                text: oData.ClassType + " " + oData.ClassNum + " " + oData.ClassNumDescr,
                classType: oData.ClassType,
                classNum: oData.ClassNum,
                internalClass: oData.InternalClass,
                nodes: []
            };
        },

        onOpenAnItemOnTree: function (oEvent) {

            const bExpanded = oEvent.getParameter("expanded");
            if (!bExpanded) {
                return;
            }

            const iItemIndex = oEvent.getParameter("itemIndex");
            const oItemContext = oEvent.getParameter("itemContext");

            const oTree = this.byId("ClassTree");
            const oModel = this.getView().getModel("Tree");
            const sPath = oItemContext.getPath();
            const oCurrentNode = oModel.getProperty(sPath);
            this._loadOnDemand(oModel, oCurrentNode, sPath, oTree.getItems()[iItemIndex].getLevel());
        },

        /*
         * Load descendants asynchronously.
         */
        _loadOnDemand: function (oModel, oCurrentNode, sPath) {

            const aChildNodes = oCurrentNode.nodes.map(oClass => {
                return new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                    path: "InternalClass",
                    operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,
                    value1: oClass.internalClass
                });

            });

            this._readClassification(aChildNodes)
                .then(aNewNodes => oModel.setProperty(sPath + "/nodes", aNewNodes));
        },

        /*
         * When the item in the tree is getting pressed.
         */
        onClassPressed: function (oEvent) {
            const oRow = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("Tree").getObject();
            this.getRouter().navTo("characteristic", {
                internalclassnum: oRow.internalClass
            });
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message the HTTP request for the Search.controller.js gets in response? It is not displayed in your screenshots.

Comment: From experience, I'd guess that you have an error in some other controller that breaks the whole app and prevents that further controllers are loaded. As you say "sometimes", this indicates that the error has to do with the order and speed in that requests are served and controls are initiated; maybe some component trying to access some control/view/controller that's not available yet?

Comment: The error message is provided on the image:`Flexibility service is not available`.

Comment: could you please provide the source code of such controller and its view?

Comment: When do you try to load the Search controller?  This is possible that the code is breaking where you perform navigation or loading the controller?

Comment: can you look into the network tab of you dev tools and post what the exact response for the request on the search controller is?

Comment: Can you check your namespace? I am not sure if this is enough to find the controller: controllerName="example.Search"

Comment: Why does "Flexibility service is not available" indicate that it fails to load a controller? It indicates that it failed to contact the flexibility service. Which may not even be a problem, only means you cannot personalize the smart controls. Both your screenshots show that error - also the working one.

Comment: I update my post.

Comment: what other errors are on your console?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the flexibility services only work in the Fiori launchpad, not in the webide sandbox launchpad. Do you get the same issue if you deploy?